# React js - Clarification needed for timer

Tags: reactjs

I just saw the tutorial of creating a timer and tried it on my own but am not sure how they are able to subtract new Date() - Date.now() ; if i hardcode this , it gives me 0 .But if the Date.now() when passed as a prop it gets incremented . Can anyone please Explain ??

This is my App.js file.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Timer from './Timer';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>

        <Timer start={Date.now()} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my Timer.js file

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

componentDidMount()
{
  console.log("component is mounted");
  setInterval(this.timer,1000);
}

constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {clock:0};
  this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);
}

timer()
{
  this.setState( {clock:new Date() - this.props.start} );

}

  render(){

    var clock = Math.round(this.state.clock/1000);
    return(
      <div>
        <p> you are in this site for </p>
        <span > {clock} </span>
        <br />
        <p> seconds </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Timer ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Reason it works when you subtracting the props is because your parent `App component` is rendering only once and hence the `start` prop is only set once. However when you do `new Date() - Date.now()` in the child component which is rerendered every second because of the `state` update in the child component which is triggered by the setInterval function, both values are evaluated and hence they result in `0`

Comment: That was helpfull thanks a lot . But when i console log new Date() -> it gives me the o/p as object . But how can we subtract a number from Object .

Comment: @Shyam you can use the `getTime` method on the Date object and get the timestamp which you can substract the Date.now() from. Basically: `var date = new Date();`  and then : `date.getTime() - Date.now()`

Comment: @DanielAndrei Thanks mate . But the above code works too , which makes me puzzeled .

Comment: That automatic conversion allows you to subtract the date, basically it would converting it to epoc time

Comment: @Shubham Khatri  It really helped . Thanks a lot  .

Comment: See this on how to accept an answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow